# How to handle relationship in coredata

Tags: ios, core-data

Hi so let's assume that I have an API that gets the category and its ID

```
let category = ["Armchairs", "Sofas", "Office", "Chairs", "Tables", "Lamps", "Spare Parts"]
let categoryId = [24,23,25,26,27,28,42]
```

and here's a sample sub category of **Armchair** with id **24** *(Query on category table and get all sub category with parent_id = 24)*

```
let subCat = ["New","Hot", "Used"]
let subCatId = [89,90,91]
```

so for item #1

> id:100 , name:Armchair Item, categ_id:89

how can I create the coredata model for this that when I query its parent category which is (24) it will find all the items in its subcategory?

here's my coredata

[image]

Additional Question: Is my coredata structure right? Should I put a sub_categ_id field?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have relations built first. Category and SubCategory. to my viewpoint its Many to Many. and you need to have ParentId in Sub Category as well.

So when you query ex: `getAllItemsByParentId:24` all the New,Old,Used items will be load.

You can create table like this.

[image]

**Updated :**

So i have relationship built like this.

[image]

and you can see `mainId` in Category table as well. when you insert item to category table mainId also will be inserted. so you only need to query the id id only. ex: where all the objects has `mainId = 24`. i hope you get the idea.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. Can you show me how is it like based on my model? Can you do it with my current model?